# Creating a super use with docker-compose

Tags: django, docker-compose

Am new to docker and am trying to create a super user using this command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py 
createsuperuser"
```

I keep getting `Error response from daemon: No such container: 3316a457be585979396635f940978c6942eaf969da69f7f86fc4dba6375fd923`

However, when I ran `docker ps`, There are no containers listed.
How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if you removed the container or changed its name. Try to run:

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py createsuperuser"
```

instead.

Also make sure you defined the app service in your `docker-compose.yml`.